# Mixture model with covariance matrix with varying variances and equal covariances

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, latent-class

In some illustrations of mixture models, the covariance matrix is structured to have varying variances and equal covariances between mixture components.

For example, [Pastor et al. (2007)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0361476X06000543) (I'm sorry I can't find a freely-available version of this) write about a model with two mixture components and eight variables, or indicators: "This specification results in Model D and in our example eight variances and six covariances would be estimated." My understanding is that two of the variances are uniquely associated with each of the four mixture components, whereas the same six covariances are estimated for all four components.

They describe in their article a covariance matrix like the one below:

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} { \sigma  }_{ 1m }^{ 2 } & { \sigma  }_{ 21 } & { \sigma  }_{ 31 } & { \sigma  }_{ 41 } \\ { \sigma  }_{ 12 } & { \sigma  }_{ 2m }^{ 2 } & { \sigma  }_{ 23 } & { \sigma  }_{ 24 } \\ { \sigma  }_{ 13 } & { \sigma  }_{ 12 } & { \sigma  }_{ 3m }^{ 2 } & { \sigma  }_{ 33 } \\ { \sigma  }_{ 14 } & { \sigma  }_{ 12 } & { \sigma  }_{ 12 } & { \sigma  }_{ 4m }^{ 2 } \end{matrix} \right]
$$

The authors use the software `MPlus` to estimate this model. In trying to estimate similar models in the `R` packages `mclust` and `Rmixmod`, I found that this model does not seem to be available. Upon thinking about it more, I began to wonder how a covariance matrix can specify different variances but equal covariances.

- Would not changing the variances always change the covariances, too?
- More generally: **Is it possible to specify a mixture model with covariance matrix with varying variances and equal covariances?**

Comment: Should be possible in R. Based on [this documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmixmod/Rmixmod.pdf), `Rmixmod` has 14 implementations of GMM. A quote from the file: `In the Gaussian case, fourteen models are implemented.... They depend on constraints on the variance matrix such as same variance matrix between clusters, spherical variance matrix... `

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with `Rmixmod`, and I tried all of the models but none of them fit the bill. I also tried `mclust`, which allows for a similar number of implementations, and none worked. More importantly, it seems like conceptually there are problems. Here's a response to a message to Chris Fraley, who is an author of `mclust`: "If the diagonal values differ across mixture components, then the covariances can't be the same. Mclust allows you to keep constant or to vary the volume (scale), shape (diagonal values), and/or orientation of the covariance across mixture components."